# Why are there so many files in the Silverlight Bin when I build my project?

Tags: silverlight, debugging, release, bin

There's just so many files. The XAP file, DLL file, HTML file, PDB File, and then I have all these folders with 2 letter words where inside each folders are 2 dll files.

What do these files (in general) represent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XAP file represents the Silverlight application (Silverlight Application Package, the X likely refers to the XAML base of Silverlight).

DLL files are your application's dependencies, some of which are created to facilitate serialization and localization.

Because Silverlight is browser-hosted, it requires an HTML page to host the control when you debug it.

The PDB file contains the "program database" which includes all the metadata Visual Studio uses to provide those nice descriptive tooltips when you mouse over a variable in the IDE.

Folders with two letters represent country codes and are used for localization.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need all of them to deploy to a webserver?

Comment: The XAP file is the most important file. MSDN has [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921170%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx) page describing how to deploy a Silverlight application to a web server.